# Select with sum() case

Tags: mysql, case

I am trying to make this query work and i can't find the problem:

```
"SELECT  "
        . "CASE victima "
        . "WHEN LIKE serviciul_sursei THEN SUM(nr_victime) as nr_vict FROM listaint WHERE victima = '".$victima[$k0]."' "
        . "WHEN NOT LIKE serviciul_sursei THEN SUM(nr_victime) as nr_vict1 FROM listaint WHERE serviciul_sursei = '".$victima[$k0]."' "
        . "END "
```

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: Case...end is an expression that can appear in the select field list and elsewhere, but it can't *contain* from or where clauses.  Step back and describe what you are attempting to do

Comment: I am trying to make a sum of victims where the values of two column fields are the same and another sum of the victims where the values of the two column fields are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good Day,

### Problems

1. You do not specify a table where it should select from after your `end` tag.
2. You should also specify the columns you want to select before the `case` tag.
3. You are also using the `like` operation wrong. When `column` like `predicate`
   Then....

- here is an example of a case query

  ```
  SELECT OrderID, Quantity,
  CASE WHEN Quantity > 30 THEN 'The quantity is greater than 30'
  WHEN Quantity = 30 THEN 'The quantity is 30'
  WHEN Quantity like '10%' THEN 'The quantity is like 10'
  ELSE 'The quantity is under 30'
  END AS QuantityText
  FROM OrderDetails;
  ```

You can run this query here [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_case) Case Query

Read more about [Case information](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/func_mysql_case.asp)

Read more about [Like Information](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_like.asp)

- Example SUM Case query

  ```
  SELECT OrderID, Quantity,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Quantity like '10%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) likeCount,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Quantity > 25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) greaterCount 
  FROM OrderDetails;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not sure if I correctly understood your needs):

```
SELECT  
     SUM(if(victima like serviciul_sursei, nr_victime,0)) as nr_vict, 
     SUM(if(victima not like serviciul_sursei,nr_victime,0)) as nr_vict1 
FROM listaint
```